# Why is there no API about sort in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Why is there no API about sort in Spark Streaming? Like `sortByKey()` or `sortBy()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguably sorting is the one of the least useful transformations in streaming. Any order you can enforce is limited to a single batch or a single window operation. Nevertheless you can apply an arbitrary transformations using `DStream.transform` so nothing stops you from using transformations like `sortByKey` or `orderBy`.

Comment: i don't think it's the least useful, eg you might want a real-time list of  the most common hashtags/whatever

Comment: @maxymoo You got a point, although this is rather tricky part. In general for `top-n` kind of problems it is better to avoid  full sort whatsoever. So it could be more useful to have `top` or `takeOrdered` equivalents on stream than actual sort.

Comment: this is a good point, in the example `TwitterPopularTags.scala` in the official spark project they do use sortbykey, although maybe it's just for the sake of a slightly simpler example